# Ayuda con Visual Studio Code y su plugin ftp-simple

Tags: vscode

Buen dia. Recien instale Visual Studio Code y una de las cosas importantes que deseo configurar es una manera de conectar directo a un FTP y editar los archivos directo en el servidor. Sucede que he instalado ftp-simple https://github.com/humy2833/FTP-Simple pero al configurar el primer Host, intento abrirlo en "Remote directory open to workspace", sin embargo no sucede nada.
He revisado la consola de SALIDA y que queda así:

[2018-11-24 08:34:45] (NOMBREdHOST) - FTP Connecting...

Por favor, alguna ayuda para que Visual Studio Code y ftp-simple me funcionen.
Mil Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo tengo funcionando. Lo he descargado del Visal Studio Marketplace, aquí esta el [enlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple).

En el mismo enlace te dice cómo configurarlo.

Igual te dejo un ejemplo.

```
[
    {
        "name": "my server1",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "id",
        "password": "pw",
        "path" : "/"
    },
{
        "name": "my server21",
.....
}

]
```

Suerte!